# Declaring @Resource and @EJB at the class level in Java EE6

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0, jndi

Is there any situation still ( given that Java EE6 has  java:global/, app/, module/ naming
standards) that necessitates declaring EJBs or Resources like the example below?

```
@EJB (name = "ejb/PlaceBid", beanInterface = PlaceBid.class)
public class ActionBazaarBidControllerServlet extends HttpServlet {

}
```

Looking up PlaceBid in the helper class used by `ActionBazaarBidControllerServlet`

```
PlaceBid placeBid = (PlaceBid)context.lookup("java:comp/env/ejb/PlaceBid");
```

Comment: Why would you declare a servlet as an `@EJB`?

Comment: Probably, to use a helper class inside the servlet that is not managed(non-entity)?

Comment: I don't see how that makes a difference...

Comment: @Matt the class-level EJB annotation does not declare the servlet "as an EJB", it declares an EJB reference within the servlet component namespace.  @Onur, perhaps you can clarify what you mean by "like this"?  Do you mean "why declare a class-level reference in java:comp rather than java:module"?

Comment: @bkail Yes, the actual question is why would we need to declare @EJB at the class level when we could get away with java:module or java:app.

Comment: @Matt, adding to bkail: Simply said, @EJB inserts a PlaceBid reference into JNDI. It's a fairly confusing annotation used this way. Perhaps @ENC or @JNDI would be much clearer. To the casual (and even experienced reader sometimes!) it indeed reads as-if the class was declared to be an EJB, but for this the annotations @Stateless, @Stateful, @Singleton and @MessageDriven are used.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `java:comp/env/` namespace is sometimes a little understood feature. This namespace corresponds to what is called the `Enterprise Naming Context` (ENC).

It's like a private "hashmap" associated with each component, with the entire web module being treated as one component and individual EJB beans each being components as well.

You use this private namespace mostly for **aliasing purposes**. If you map something under "ejb/PlaceBid", then all (helper) code can use "ejb/PlaceBid" and at one global location (the servlet in this case, but it could also be XML) you can determine what is exactly mapped to it. If all code went directly to `java:global/...` then there might be dozens of hardcoded dependencies to this name.

So, you would use this if you need the extra redirection.

---

Some other things to note:

1.
With the EJB SessionContext you can reference this namespace directly, as-in:

```
PlaceBid placeBid = (PlaceBid)sessionContext.lookup("ejb/PlaceBid");
```

Here "ejb/PlaceBid" is a relative name into the ENC.

2.
As mentioned, the ENC is private for each component. Different EJBs can have a given relative name mapped differently. `context.lookup("java:comp/env/ejb/PlaceBid")` can thus return something different depending on from which component you make the call.

3.
Historically, the ENC predated what we now call *injection*. In a way, when you specified a mapping in XML, you 'injected' something into the private "hashmap" associated with that component. The modern version injects into fields, constructors or properties (setters), but the old version injected into 'keys'.

Even in EJB3.1, the historical 'injection' mechanism is still active under the hood. If you perform a seemingly normal injection using @EJB on a field, then this also automatically creates an entry in the JNDI ENC. E.g.

```
package test;

@Stateless
public class MyBean {

   @EJB
   private MyService myService;

}
```

In this case, whatever is injected into myService is also stored in the ENC under name `java:comp/env/test.MyBean/myService`. To complete the link with the @EJB annotation you used on the Servlet: you can optionally use the `name` attribute to specify the name under which the reference is stored in the ENC:

```
@Stateless
public class MyBean {

   @EJB(name = "ejb/PlaceBid")
   private MyService myService;

}
```

A little counter-intuitive, but in most cases the `name` attribute here is thus not something that points to a *source* where the object to be injected is taken from, but it's used as a *target* in the ENC to inject into.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation.

Comment: Hi, could I have a question after this long time? :)

what is the scope of stored values in ENC, is it component, module or application (in ejb 3.1) ?

Comment: @Moro the ENC is per component, which in the case of EJB is a single bean.

Comment: @ArjanTijms when you talk about ENC as a private Hashmap per EJB component what will be the likely keys and values for that? Lets say I have a mapping like "ejb/PlaceBean" to `PlaceBean EJB` as an example. How can that HashMap have more than one key value pair? An example will help.

Comment: @Geek, it's only conceptually a map, more correctly would be a tree or a directory. Seen as a map though the key in the example above is "ejb/PlaceBid" and the value is "PlaceBid". Another key could be "foo" and its value could be some Datasource. The variations are really endless.

Comment: @ArjanTijms Why the whole web module is treated as a single component? I mean if EJB's are treated as individual components, then why not for eg. the individual JSF Managed Beans be also treated the same way? As far as I understand they are similarly managed by the container. So what is the conceptual reasoning behind this taxonomy?

Comment: @Geek >Why the whole web module is treated as a single component? - This is a historical left over. I'm not sure if anyone still involved with Java EE these days knows why this decision was taken. It has some other weird consequences, like the way a data-source is defined in ejb-jar. See this post from Java EE spec lead Bill Shannon: https://java.net/projects/javaee-spec/lists/users/archive/2012-05/message/33

Comment: @Geek >`individual JSF Managed Beans be also treated the same way? As far as I understand they are similarly managed by the container.` - They are managed beans and are indeed managed by the container, but "managed beans" is a newer concept. Java EE component namespaces are a different and older concept. A managed bean is not necessarily a Java EE component (most aren't) but a single EJB bean is both a managed bean and a Java EE component (which thus have its own component namespace).

Answer (score 0):

Declaring a reference using a class-level annotation and declaring a reference using a java:module, java:app, or java:global name are distinct features.

You would use a class-level annotation to declare a reference if you don't need injection but you don't want to use XML.

You would use a java:module, java:app, or java:global name (regardless of how the reference is defined) if you want multiple components in the module, app, or server to have access to the same reference.  For example, so that you are only required to define a binding for the reference once rather than repeating the same binding information for each identical binding in the module (or in the app or for all apps in the server).