# Can you help me understand the purpose of java:comp/env (The Enterprise Naming Context aka ENC)?

Tags: java, jndi

I have been doing some reading about the JBoss Naming Service JNDI provider.

I hit something I have seen around in code a million times but I never really truly understood - the ENC.

```
// Obtain the application component's ENC
Context iniCtx = new InitialContext();
Context compEnv = (Context) iniCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");
```

I have read some information about the ENC from

[Stackoverflow article with an answer that describes ENC a bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6180144/declaring-resource-and-ejb-at-the-class-level-in-java-ee6/6185960)

[J2EE and JNDI - The Application Component Environment](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/4/html/Naming_on_JBoss-J2EE_and_JNDI___The_Application_Component_Environment.html#J2EE_and_JNDI___The_Application_Component_Environment-ENC_access_sample_code)

[Another Stackoverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6853864/ejb-jndi-enc-real-life-scenario)

However I'm really struggling to understand when and why to use the java:comp/env JNDI context. Can anyone break it down for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of the ENC is to provide an isolated, read-only namespace that the application component can rely on regardless of the type of environment in which the component is deployed.