# Access an injected resource in EJB

Tags: jakarta-ee, resources, ejb

I am reading currently the chapter [resource injection in the java-ee tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncjk.html) and I cannot apprehend the way one make use of the resource after inject it, or in other words in what way one has access to it:

**Field-Based Injection:**

```
public class SomeClass {
    @Resource(name="customerDB")
    private javax.sql.DataSource myDB;
...
}
```

**Method-Based Injection:**

```
public class SomeClass {

    private javax.sql.DataSource myDB;
...
    @Resource(name="customerDB")
    private void setMyDB(javax.sql.DataSource ds) {
        myDB = ds;
    }
...
}
```

**Class-Based Injection:**

```
@Resource(name="myMessageQueue",
                type="javax.jms.ConnectionFactory")
public class SomeMessageBean {
...
}
```

I suppose in the `class-based` it is possible only with `lookup` (how exactly?). In the first two cases however, how should one use the Resource, especially when it is defined additionally with name?

**UPDATE:**

In case it is not completely clear, my question concerns the following topics:

1) in the `field-` or `method-based injection` do I access the resource like:

```
myDB.someMethod();
```

or

```
customerDB.someMethod();
```

If the first is right, what is the purpose of the `name`? Can I access it also with `lookup`?

2) How I access it in the `class-based injection`? I suppose with `lookup` but under which path?

Comment: You use the injected fields inside all the methods of the bean like you would use any other field in any other Java class. I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If the first is right, what is the purpose of the name? Can I access it also with lookup?

The great difficulty and a major cause of confusion in JNDI and the massively overloaded `@Resource` annotation, is that `name` refers to the local ENC space that's associated with a component (in case of an EJB bean, it's the single Bean). You can access this space from an initial context using `java:comp/env`.

'name' is both a TARGET name and a SOURCE name. As a target name, it doesn't lookup things, but stores something in the ENC. If something has already been mapped into the ENC, e.g. via XML, then it serves as a source name (it's used to lookup from the ENC).

'lookup' however always does what it says it does; it does a lookup in the "GLOBAL" JNDI namespace, e.g. `java:app/`, `java:module/` etc. Note that I put global between quotes, as even those name spaces are still relative to the location from which the JNDI lookup is done.

> How I access it in the class-based injection?

Class-based injection is the annotation equivalent of the XML syntax for mapping something into the ENC of a component. It doesn't IMHO translate well to modern programming practices. After having injected something into the ENC, you can look it up again via an `InitialContext` using the aforementioned `java:comp/env` space.

E.g. given

```
@Resource(name="myMessageQueue",
                type="javax.jms.ConnectionFactory")
public class SomeMessageBean {
...
}
```

You can do the following lookup from anywhere WITHIN the call chain of a method to SomeMessageBean, UP TILL the next call to a Java EE component (which sets a new ENC context):

```
try {
    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new InitialContext().lookup("myMessageQueue");
} catch (NamingException e) {
   ...
}
```

All in all `@Resource` is an attempt to somewhat modernize the ancient pre-cursor to injection in Java EE, but because of legacy concerns it adds tons of complexity itself. IMHO it would be better if the whole of Java EE would migrate to `@Inject`, which has a much clearer and less overloaded semantics.

See also: [Declaring @Resource and @EJB at the class level in Java EE6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6180144/declaring-resource-and-ejb-at-the-class-level-in-java-ee6)

Comment: +1 for the explanation. So `@Resource(name="foo")` is actually a shortcut for `@Resource(name="foo", lookup="foo")`, is that right? And, in addition to injecting the field/method, it also creates a "local" alias in the ENC to the globally-named "foo" resource, right?

Comment: It seems to me also strange that "name" and "lookup" fullfil the same purpose.

Comment: @JBNizet basically, but just `@Resource(name="foo")` will not lookup a `foo` (as a top-level JNDI entry), but only `java:comp/env/foo` if it's there. When specifying both `name` and `lookup` its indeed akin to an alias when used at the class level. Because of the many overloads of `@Resource` and the sometimes ambiguous meanings it's rather hard to remember everything 100% correct.

Comment: @arjacsoh >`It seems to me also strange that "name" and "lookup" fulfill the same purpose.` - They are different, but I know it's confusing. And there's also the `mappedName` to make it even more confusing :P

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question:

```
@Resource(name="customerDB")
private javax.sql.DataSource myDB;
```

The above code means: inject the private field `myDB` with the DataSource named `"customerDB"`. The name of the field and the name of the resource are two completely different things. The variable name is up to you, and the resource name must the the name of a DataSource configured in JNDI.

And of course, you use `myDB` to access the field, because that's what the name of the field is. Annotations are just metadata associated to regular Java classes, fields and methods. They don't change how Java works: to access a field, you use the name of the field. Not the name of a Java EE annotation associated with the field.

Regarding your second question, to be fair, I have no idea whay class-based injection means and when it can be useful.