# JNDI Global and JNDI ENC

Tags: jakarta-ee, jndi

I am learning and working with Java EE projects. I'm a little confused regarding JNDI and specifically the JNDI Enterprise Naming Context (ENC). It's not very easy to find sites talking clearly about this subject.

Can anyone point me to good books or links talking about this subject?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ENV can indeed be a confusing concept. I explained it some time ago here: [Declaring @Resource and @EJB at the class level in Java EE6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6180144/declaring-resource-and-ejb-at-the-class-level-in-java-ee6/6185960#6185960)

The concept is also discussed in the book [Enterprise JavaBeans 3.1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596158025).